# fx:deploy application not working but the Java jar is working - Gluon Project

Tags: java, ant, gluon-mobile

I've got my gluon project and it works when run from the jar (by command line and double click) which is created by the Netbeans IDE and when you use the ide run task. But I'm also trying to deploy to an msi and an exe and later on a dmg. When I use ant to do the deployment I get the application created and it installs fine. But when you try to run it it says cannot find main method in class. Now as far as I know you don't put a main method into a gluon application and when I've tried to even put a basic main method into the main class I get a null pointer exception thrown at me. I'm not sure what the solution is here, I've provided by build.xml file that I'm using to deploy via ant.

```
<project name="No Panics Self Helper"
 xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <file name="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar"/>
        </filelist>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>

 <delete dir="dist/bundles/NoPanicsSelfHelper/runtime/jre"/>
 <mkdir dir="dist/bundles/NoPanicsSelfHelper/runtime/jre"/>
 <copy todir="dist/bundles/NoPanicsSelfHelper/runtime/jre">
<fileset dir="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre" />
 </copy>
<fx:deploy nativeBundles="all" width="600" height="400"
       outdir="${basedir}/dist" outfile="NoPanicsSelfHelper">
<fx:application name="NoPanicsSelfHelper" mainClass="com.nopanicsselfhelper.NoPanicsSelfHelper"/>
<fx:resources>
    <!-- include application jars -->
    <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="NoPanicsSelfHelper.jar"/>       

    <fileset dir="dist/resources">
    <include name="**"/>
    </fileset>
</fx:resources>
<!-- Custom JVM setup for application -->
<fx:platform>
    <fx:jvmarg value="-Xmx2048m"/>
    <fx:jvmarg value="-verbose:jni"/>
</fx:platform>
<fx:platform basedir="${java.home}"/>      
<fx:platform basedir="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91"/>
<!-- request user level installation -->
<fx:preferences install="false"/>
</fx:deploy>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer was too simple. Just add the below.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(NoPanicsSelfHelper.class);
    }
```